# After executing connectedCheck, Realm generated classes are included in coverage report

Tags: android, testing, gradle, realm, jacoco

The issue is that Jacoco reports Realm generated classes after executing `./gradlew connectedCheck` with test coverage enabled.

Realm generates tons of code, which makes coverage reports not reliable.

That is how test coverage looks like:
[image: Actual coverage report]

What is the simplest way to remove `io.realm` package from `connectedCheck` report?

Answer (score 2):

If I take the [Google GithubBrowserSample into account which has the following task in its build.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/5ec49a4bcdada748b4968138c4182deef3741123/GithubBrowserSample/app/build.gradle):

```
task fullCoverageReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    dependsOn 'createDebugCoverageReport'
    dependsOn 'testDebugUnitTest'
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*',
                      '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*',
                      '**/*_MembersInjector.class',
                      '**/Dagger*Component.class',
                      '**/Dagger*Component$Builder.class',
                      '**/*_*Factory.class',
                      '**/*ComponentImpl.class',
                      '**/*SubComponentBuilder.class']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
            "outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec"
    ])
}
```

You could most likely add a file filter such as `io.realm.*RealmProxy.class`.

Comment: It didn't work with that pattern, but this one works: `**/io/realm/*`